# How to use random array output as a for-loop CSS attribute in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I'm trying to use an array of CSS color attributes in a for-loop that appends to a div.  I think the problem may be the syntax of quotation marks, as there's multiple ones to worry about.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var color_array = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"];
var randColor = color_array[Math.floor(Math.random() * color_array.length)];

for (i = 1; i <= 500; i++) {
    $("#box").append("<div style='background-color:' + randColor + '; height:10px; width:10px; float:left;'></div>");
}
});
```

Is there any easier way to achieve this?

Comment: Is your code broken, or just sub-optimal? If it's the latter, http://codereview.stackexchange.com is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#box").append("<div style='background-color:" + randColor + "; height:10px; width:10px; float:left;'></div>");
```

You missed the closing `"`.

Comment: replace `randColor + "';` with `randColor + ";`, and you're 100% correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try using RGB color value, specified with: `rgb(red, green, blue)`. Each parameter `(red, green, and blue)` defines the intensity of the color and can be an integer between 0 and 255 or a percentage value (from 0% to 100%).

```
var rgb = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    rgb.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255));

myDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb('+ rgb.join(',') +')';
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/v7RgF/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$(function () {
    var color_array = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"],
        randColor = color_array[Math.floor(Math.random() * color_array.length)],
        elementArray = [];

    for (i = 1; i <= 500; i++) {
        elementArray.push($('<div />', { "css": { "background-color": randColor, "height": "10px", "width": "10px", "float": "left" }}));
    }

    $('#box').append(elementArray);
});
```

I made a few modifications.

- Push each element to an array and append the array once at the end.
- By using the `$('<div />', { ... })` syntax, you allow jQuery to use the faster native function `document.createElement(...);`.

Answer (score 1):

This would really better regarding performance:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sag4F/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var color_array = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"];
    var randColor = color_array[Math.floor(Math.random() * color_array.length)];

    $("#box").append(
       new Array(500 + 1).join("<div style='background-color:"+randColor+"; height:10px; width:10px; float:left;'></div>")
    );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You're right the quotes aren't in the right place. See my changes down below. The point of interest is the line on `$('#box').append(...)`

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

      var color_array = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"];
      var randColor = color_array[Math.floor(Math.random() * color_array.length)];

      for (i = 1; i <= 500; i++) {
        $("#box").append("<div style='background-color:" + randColor + "; height:10px; width:10px; float:left;'></div>");
      }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

It's a simple problem of string concatenation:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 500; i++) {
    $("#box").append("<div style='background-color:" + randColor + "'; height:10px; width:10px; float:left;'></div>");
}
```

But you have other ways to achieve this:

```
// it's better to select your box once, rather than 500 times.
var box = $('#box');
for (var i = 1; i <= 500; i++) {
    // creates a "floating" div (not attached yet), and style it.
    var div = $('<div>').css({backgroundColor: randColor, height: 10, width: 10, float: 'left'});
    // attach your div to the dom.
    box.append(div);
}
```